# Specify which node is the root in simple sfnetworks

Tags: r, tidygraph, sfnetwork

I have a rooted tree with spatially explicit edges that consists of just one edge and two nodes.

**Data**

```
n01 = st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))
n02 = st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 10)))

from = c(1)
to = c(2)

nodes = st_as_sf(c(n01, n02))
edges = data.frame(from = from, to = to)

G = sfnetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  convert(to_spatial_explicit, .clean = TRUE)
> G
# A sfnetwork with 2 nodes and 1 edges
#
# CRS:  NA 
#
# A rooted tree with spatially explicit edges
#
# Node Data:     2 x 1 (active)
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 0 ymax: 10
        x
  <POINT>
1   (0 0)
2  (0 10)
#
# Edge Data:     1 x 3
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 0 ymax: 10
   from    to     geometry
  <int> <int> <LINESTRING>
1     1     2  (0 0, 0 10)
```

When I check which `node_is_root()` I see that it's the first node.

```
> with_graph(G, node_is_root())
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Is it possible to have it the other way around?

**Desired output**

```
> with_graph(G, node_is_root())
[1] FALSE TRUE
```

Note: The mode has to be `"in"` when calling further functions like `st_network_path()` or `st_network_cost()` on the graph because each node represents the source or mouth of a river so the results wouldn't be correct if mode was switched to `"out"` for those cases with only one edge.

Comment: Hi! If I consider just the data showed in this question, then I think you can simply set `from = 2` and `to = 1` and get the desired result. I don't know if this procedure can be generalised to "real world" data. Can you add more details if that doesn't answer your question?

Comment: `G %>% activate("edges") %>% mutate(from = 2, to = 1)`
still results in `from = 1` and `to = 2`. Can `from` and `to` be mutated?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to invert the `from` and `to` before creating the `sfnetwork` object. For example:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(tidygraph)
library(sfnetworks)
```

Create data

```r
n01 = st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))
n02 = st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 10)))

from = 2L
to = 1L

nodes = st_as_sf(c(n01, n02))
edges = data.frame(from = from, to = to)
```

Create network object

```r
G = sfnetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  convert(to_spatial_explicit, .clean = TRUE)
#> Checking if spatial network structure is valid...
#> Spatial network structure is valid
```

Check result

```r
G
#> # A sfnetwork with 2 nodes and 1 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  NA 
#> #
#> # A rooted tree with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     2 x 1 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 0 ymax: 10
#>         x
#>   <POINT>
#> 1   (0 0)
#> 2  (0 10)
#> #
#> # Edge Data:     1 x 3
#> # Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 0 ymax: 10
#>    from    to     geometry
#>   <int> <int> <LINESTRING>
#> 1     2     1  (0 10, 0 0)
```

Check output

```r
with_graph(G, node_is_root())
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>